# Question ban warning although I haven't yet asked anything

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

If I go to [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) on Super User I get this message displayed:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

However, [I've not yet asked anything](https://superuser.com/users/245640/silverlightfox?tab=questions). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked two questions:

- [One](https://superuser.com/questions/747910/how-to-set-iptables-to-drop-packets-that-im-not-listening-on) that was migrated to Unix.SE on your own request where you then [deleted it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128259/how-to-set-iptables-to-drop-packets-that-im-not-listening-on) (so this counts as a rejected migration on our site)
- [Another one](https://superuser.com/questions/775932/hibernation-via-power-button-vs-start-menu) that was closed as primarily opinion-based and auto-deleted later

Basically, two closed and deleted questions, which negatively impact your account's standing.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't notified about the second one. I'm not sure why it was closed for the reason of being `primarily opinion-based` as I asked for solid evidence either way rather than opinion. If I'd known I would have contested it at the time.

Comment: I looked at the question in more detail and reopened it. It's not like it'll spur discussion; it might just never get an answer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I could always add a bounty in future maybe.