# I'm warned about the bad quality of my questions, yet I see no questions

Tags: support, bad-questions

I logged in today to ask about a problem I have and the first thing I saw is this:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Yet, when I look at my profile, I see no questions. My reputation is what it should be when I have no question and my badge count is also the same as it should be when I log to a SE site.

This is probably similar to [Question ban warning although I haven't yet asked anything](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8581/297010), since I remember I posted one or two questions over here.

So what's going on? Why can't I see my "bad" questions? Usually on StackOverflow when I self-delete a question/answer, I'm still able to see it (I think... since it rarely happens).

Well, shortly, if my questions are supposedly bad *and* I'm about to get banned, I should be able to see my question *with* the reason for deletion so that I can improve myself *and* the questions instead of hiding all that data. Finally, my rep on other sites should be a factor in *not* being banned.

Comment: You have 2 deleted questions. Not quite sure why you can't see them tho, and can't remember off the top of my head if that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/740037/i-want-to-use-another-proxy-for-google-drive and http://superuser.com/questions/718419/i-cannot-share-folders-in-vmware-player-6-host-win-7-guest-centos-6-4 .

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I read from a SE employee at some point that deleted questions/answers are counted multiple times in the quality equation.  I couldn't find that statement again if I tried though.  I might also have read into the statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JourneymanGeek has linked your two deleted questions in the comments.

I believe that after 60 days your deleted posts are no longer shown to you, to keep your profile clean. Moderators can see them and (I believe) 10k users can as well. This has been [discussed on meta.StackExhange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) so I will not go into the reasoning here.

You *probably* are reasonably okay, neither of your deleted questions received much in the way of downvotes so I doubt you will hit the block with your current activity.

As to getting the notice in the first place... Why should your reputation on one site translate to some undefined "trustworthiness" on another? You can't assume that you know what makes a good post on Judaism just because you know how to program a computer. You have to prove that you can work within the community of each site individually, otherwise anyone who has good rep on one site could effectively troll another with impunity if the mood took them.

Granted though, your questions were not bad and the only reason they were deleted was because Community cleaned them up. In this case I don't think you should have gotten the warning, but the workings of *that* system is a mystery to everyone but the devs.

Comment: The two questions linked by JourneymanGeek are visible to me as a regular user here, and show as deleted.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I believe that is because you have [10k rep](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). One of the perks (or curses, depending on your perspective) is that you can see deleted posts. When I got to 10k the site became a horrifying mess and tangle of deleted posts.

Comment: Yes, seeing deleted posts is a 10k privilege (on graduated sites; on beta sites it's lower, I think 2k but could be wrong). And it's a trivial fix with Adblock if you want that. Of course, with a diamond, that might not be the best thing for you to do on SU... ;-)